# How flaging element in a row with respect to other elements in other rows in a matrix in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have the following rectangular array :

[image]

[example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rip9dt5c2nt0wzu/gdffeyyuwuygegrg.png?dl=0)

I need to check if any cell is surrounded by zeros from all sides: horizontal, vertical, and diagonal as in the example.

Comment: This is a nightmare. you need to learn how to partition code into small function! Say `processNeighbour( int row, int col)`. There is a rule of thumb: Not piece of code should go over more than one or two screens. (Some say 5-10 lines)

Comment: Can you please add the wrong result it gave you? It might help us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a better method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] chromosome = {
                {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,},
                {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,},
                {1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,},
                {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,},
                {1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,},
                {1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,},
                {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,},
                {1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,},
                {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
                {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,}
                       };

            Boolean results11 = TestZero(chromosome, 1, 1);
            Boolean results85 = TestZero(chromosome, 8, 5);
        }

        static Boolean TestZero(int[,] array, int rowIndex, int colIndex)
        {
            if((rowIndex <= 0) || (rowIndex >= array.GetUpperBound(0)) || (colIndex <= 0) || (colIndex >= array.GetUpperBound(1))) return false;

            for(int i = rowIndex - 1; i <= rowIndex + 1; i++)
            {
                for(int j = colIndex - 1; j <= colIndex + 1; j++)
                {
                    if((i != rowIndex) && (j != colIndex))
                    {
                        if(array[i,j] == 1) return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```